# To what extent does the United States government have sovereign immunity from state governments?

Tags: united-states

This question is the reverse of [Does the sovereign immunity clause prevent the federal government from suing states through the federal court in any situation?](https://law.stackexchange.com/q/68071/765). In an answer to that question, it is said that states do not have sovereign immunity from the United States since the United States is a "superior sovereign".

What about when a state brings suit against the federal government? In particular, what kinds of lawsuits would fall into the following categories (if any) and why?

1. Sovereign immunity does not apply at all when the plaintiff is a state
2. Sovereign immunity applies and the suit would be barred if it were brought by a citizen, but federal law has waived that immunity when the plaintiff is a state
3. Sovereign immunity applies and has not been waived, so in these cases states are unable to sue the federal government